# php insert database not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm wondering why the code below can't add my data into the database, there's no error message whatsoever.

trans_id is in INT(11) data type, subject and useid is in VARCHAR(45).

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","user","pass");
if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect to the database! ' . mysql_error());
}

//Accessing the database
$db_selected = mysql_select_db("ebook", $con);
if (!$db_selected) {
    die ('Database error!' . mysql_error());
}
else
    mysql_query($con, "INSERT INTO free_chapters (trans_id, subject, useid) VALUES ($transactionId, 'Chemistry', $useid)");
```

Comment: What if you change your query to `mysql_query("...") or die(mysql_error());`

Comment: if `useid` is varchar, you'll need single quotes around it, too..

Answer (score 2):

First of all you shouldn't be using `mysql_*` functions, as they are outdated, and are huge security risk, so please learn about `mysqli_` or `PDO`

second, `mysql_query()` should take the `dsn` **as a second parameter, not first.** Meaning you need to change to `mysql_query('your statement', $conn)` but you are doing it the opposite`

Answer (score 1):

You have wrong order of params in mysql_query.
It should be:

```
mysql_query ( string $query [, resource $link_identifier = NULL ] );
```

or in your case:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO free_chapters (trans_id, subject, useid) 
VALUES ($transactionId, 'Chemistry', '$useid')", $con);
```

And you should stop using mysql_ extension because:

```
This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, 
and will be removed in the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL 
extension should be used. See also MySQL: choosing an API guide and 
related FAQ for more information.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO free_chapters (trans_id, subject, useid) VALUES ($transactionId, 'Chemistry', '" . $useid . "')", $con);
```

And before the overzealous nutsos attack, let it be known that mysql is unsafe, deprecated and  can cause your cottage to spoil prematurely. Try to stay away from it.

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql_query($con, "INSERT INTO free_chapters (trans_id, subject, useid) VALUES ($transactionId, 'Chemistry', $useid)");
```

Should be as:

```
mysql_query($con, "INSERT INTO free_chapters (trans_id, subject, useid) VALUES ('$transactionId', 'Chemistry', '$useid')"
```

And use mysqli_* instead of mysql_*.

try this

Comment: First parameter should be the query itself, than the link identifier.

Answer (score 0):

(Others before me caught the error in the order of parameters)
After you change them you might want to change:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO free_chapters (trans_id, subject, useid) VALUES ($transactionId, 'Chemistry', $useid)", $con);
```

To:

```
$res = mysql_query("INSERT INTO free_chapters (trans_id, subject, useid) VALUES ($transactionId, 'Chemistry', $useid)", $con);
if (!$res) {
    die('Error during insert: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

That should give you the error message from the database and you can solve any other problems.

And of course:

After you solve the problem with this query you may want to stop using deprecated APIs and start using MySQLi or PDO_MySQL. Your code is prone SQL injection attacks if $transactionId or $useid are not properly escaped/sanitized.